# Can you help me to read this seal

Tags: character-identification, seal

Can you help me to read this seal.
Is this phrase part of a poetic or philosophical text ?

[image]

---

Many thanks for your translation and your findings.
My seal is a bronze round seal , diameter 55 mm, high 42 mm
This roughly match the infos you have found.

[image]

Could it be the seal of a library called "Wei zhai" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a Japanese artefact. The characters are

> 緯齋（學）書

From a brief Google search, the only record which came up is from a Japanese website (http://www.ezimport.co.jp/product.php?id=t533042480) which no longer is active. The residual archive text in that link says

> 美しい円形の古銅印です。書鎮にもぴったり！！「緯斎学書」でしょうか。 語句も美しい。サイズ印面径56ミリ、高さ45ミリ。
>
> *This is a beautiful circular bronze seal, perfect for calligraphy. The writing says* 「緯斎（齋）学（學）書」*, doesn't it - beautiful words indeed. The seal's surface diameter is 56 mm, and height is 45 mm.*

If your measurements match this, then you've found a residual internet comment talking about your aftefact.

Answer (score 0):

I think the words are `緯齋李？` reading from top to bottom, and right to left.

Seals typically contain the name of the seal holder. So it's unlikely to be any poetic phrases. If it's an emperor's seal, you'll see some extra characters "Someone之寶/之印" explaining the seal is the treasure of the emperor.